# com.couchbase.client.core.error.FeatureNotAvailableException: Cannot use createAsDeleted Sub-Document flag

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

com.couchbase.client.core.error.FeatureNotAvailableException: Cannot use createAsDeleted Sub-Document flag, as it is not supported by this version of the cluster\n\tat com.couchbase.client.core.msg.kv.SubdocMutateRequest.(SubdocMutateRequest.java:83)\n\tat com.couchbase.client.java.AsyncCollection.lambda$mutateInRequest$41(AsyncCollection.java:1093)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1106)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2235)\n\tat com.couchbase.client.java.AsyncCollection.mutateInRequest(AsyncCollection.java:1061)\n\tat com.couchbase.client.java.ReactiveCollection.lambda$mutateIn$22(ReactiveCollection.java:645)\n\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)\n\t... 66 common frames omitted\n\n"}

Comment: Please share the code you wrote, let's understand what the problem is according to her.

Comment: Wild guess: Does this happen when you try to use a transaction? If so, what version of the transactions library, and what version of Couchbase Server? I suspect the server version is not recent enough.

Comment: Hi Dnault, yes using transaction. server version is "6.5.1"

Comment: Please confirm , It is not working because of createAsDeleted Sub-Document flag support has been added from version "6.6" . https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/NCBC-2573

Comment: Yes, I believe that's correct; the version of the transactions library you're using requires Couchbase Server 6.6